# An error occurred whilst loading the ontology at Unknown ontology

Tags: ontology, protege

#### Opening the ontology keeps failing

I have been building an ontology using Protege 5.1 for the past few months, and suddenly encountered an issue when opening my ontology.

This error only occurred after I duplicated my `.owl` file into the same folder for back up purposes (e.g. naming the `.owl` file as `ontology-name-mar-15.owl`).

#### Error message

Clicking the red warning symbol at the upper right leads to the Protege logs, which included the following error message:

`An error occurred whilst loading the ontology at Unknown ontology: OntologyID(OntologyIRI(HTTP_LINK_TO_MY_ONTOLOGY_URI) VersionIRI()). Cause: {}`

As you can see, It did not contain any particular error message, just giving me an empty cause `{}` message, and my only clue to the problem was that the ontology loading failed, as it says that it was an `Unknown ontology`.

#### `.owl` file seems to be readable

I have worked for quite some time with my ontology, and do not want to repeat my work. Opening my `.owl` file on an online application for [OWL Visualization](http://vowl.visualdataweb.org/webvowl.html) shows that it is still readable and works.

I've come to the conclusion that Protege is the one having problems opening my ontology but am unsure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

#### Delete the `catalog.xml` file.

What I did to address my problem was to delete the `catalog-v001.xml` file which was being edited/automatically updated whenever I opened my Protege app. It is found in the same folder as the `.owl` file.

Opening the `.owl` ontology file with Protege regenerated the `catalog.xml` file and it opened the file correctly.